# How can I troubleshoot when the locate database isn't built on macOS?

Tags: macos, launchd, plist, sonoma

I”m struggling to have a `locate` database built on my Mac to index all files under `/opt`.

```sh
$ locate locate

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

Following the output of the `locate` command, to enable the `locate` command on a Mac, I did:

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`

but it returns *immediately*, instead of "*take some time*", and `ls -l /var/db/locate.database` gives `No such file or directory`.

`less /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist` shows:

```
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.apple.locate</string>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <true/>
```

My understanding is this should turn on the process:

`sudo launchctl enable system/com.apple.locate.plist`, but I still see it is disabled *afterwards*:

```
$ head /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.locate</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
```

I've started `sudo launchctl start com.apple.locate` this morning, over 7 hours ago, but so far I'm still getting: `ls: /var/db/locate.database: No such file or directory`

When I tried to get info about its status --

```sh
$ sudo launchctl list com.apple.locate
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "System";
    "Label" = "com.apple.locate";
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 256;
    "Program" = "/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb";
    );
};
```

That `LastExitStatus" = 256` looks like something is wrong. As reported before, I've also tried to run the `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` command, but it has been running for hours, but I'm still getting: `ls: /var/db/locate.database: No such file or directory`

macOS version:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.2.1
BuildVersion:       23C71
```

Can I generate an index for opt and avoid troubleshooting why the system delivered locate isn’t generating a result in hours?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150860/discussion-on-question-by-xpt-enable-the-locate-command-on-a-mac); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with rebooting and open two windows - one for Activity Monitor and another second shell to check for things as you enable the tool and check that it starts.

Run the command below to ignore the launch daemon triggering it, since you lose any output or errors...

```
me@m2 /tmp % sudo -s
Password:
root@m2 tmp # time /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb 
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb  11.35s user 18.40s system 51% cpu 57.899 total
```

On my M2 Air the database was initially built in about 3 minutes, so you should be able to catch things starting unless it aborts immediately. If you don't get any errors from the above, let's try changing your `/etc/locate.rc` file to uncomment SEARCHPATHS and have it be just /opt (or even narrower, one specific folder deeper into opt you care to test).

---

Some notes for future investigations:

`sudo launchctl load -w` should always execute immediately - it's toggling a database transaction, that another process `launchd` watches and then kicks off the actions if needed. In your case, it immediately calls `/bin/sh /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` and you can use `ps` to see this on my Mac...

```
me@m2 ~ % ps -ef|grep locate
  501 21617     1   0 28Dec23 ??         0:40.53 /usr/libexec/findmylocateagent
    0 34234     1   0  2:45PM ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
    0 34240 34234   0  2:45PM ??         0:00.02 su -fm nobody -c /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
   -2 34241 34240   0  2:45PM ??         0:00.01 /bin/sh /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
   -2 34246 34241   0  2:45PM ??         0:00.01 /bin/sh /usr/libexec/locate.mklocatedb -presort
   -2 34248 34246   0  2:45PM ??         0:00.11 locate.code /tmp/locatewJUgmcwwtV/mklocateVIzEJK1vjC/_mklocatedb34246.bigrams
  501 34251 34223   0  2:45PM ttys002    0:00.00 grep locate
```

The first and last items are not related to the `launchctl load` command - the rest are all processes that create the database file for you. Run the `ps` command before you try to request a run to check that nothing else is present on your system matching that string.

The **updatedb** program is a shell script, so you can examine it and see how it runs - changing to the user nobody to make a temporary directory (which is why you don't see the database being built - it gets moved into place if all goes well in the process).

```
me@m2 /tmp % sudo -s
Password:
root@m2 tmp # time /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb 
/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb  5.27s user 9.66s system 77% cpu 19.158 total
```

Subsequent rebuilds of the database take less than 30 seconds since my Mac in this case is otherwise idle and the system caches enough of the filesystem data to make things snappy.

Comment: _"The updatedb program is a shell script, so you can examine it and see how it runs"_ yeah, that surely helped me troubleshoot the process. and I found the reason that it works for everyone except me is that I've put GNU tools in PATH before the native ones, and the different behavior of GNU's mktemp breaks the script. case solved. Thanks.

Comment: Oh wow! So glad you’re set - I had that on the way down the list of things to check.